# Is htmlspecalchars in html value attributes enough to prevent xss?

Tags: php, html, xss

Is `htmlspecialchars()` a foolproof way of preventing any risk of an `XSS` attack on `HTML` element attributes?

For example, in this input element will the use of `htmlspecialchars()` also encoding quotes ensure total safety? 
Logically it would seem so as it would stop any string from breaking out of the context of the value attribute; or is there more that could be done?

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dangerousString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"
```

Comment: What does the value of a text input field have to do with xss protection?

Comment: In a situation where form fields are being repopulated with the data a user entered after form validation failed. With no protection a string starting with "> could end the attribute and element.

Comment: This is not possible by just entering text into a text input. It would require anipulating the DOM accordingly. And that means the attacker already has scripting access, so it is too late.

Comment: @arkascha — You are missing the point. The text is in the HTTP request. The PHP is reading it and putting it into the HTML. That is how XSS usually works.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, that's what I was trying to explain. Is my solution suitable / safe in the given situation?

Comment: @Sam — I think so, but there might be complications from things like the UTF-7 bug so I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a modern version of php, `htmlspecialchars` should do the trick.

It's important to note that you also must provide the same encoding (`utf8`) for the whole page via headers and meta tags. Otherwise, you're subject to [UTF-7 injection](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200704/xss_with_utf7.html).

Also do note, that `htmlspecialchars` is fine only for attributes like `value`, that don't interpret javascript. It's *not enough* for `src` and friends.